# Set a Custom Header in the HTTP Interceptor along with a URL change

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

When I try to add a custom header along with a URL change (based on the environment), my custom header is not appending as part of the request headers.

**Below is my HTTP Interceptor code (Angular 5):**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
        import {
          HttpRequest,
          HttpHandler,
          HttpEvent,
          HttpInterceptor
        } from '@angular/common/http';
        import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
        import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
        @Injectable()
        export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
          constructor(public auth: AuthService) {}
          intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
             let url = this.environment.api + request.url;
            request = request.clone({
              url: url,
              setHeaders: {
                Authorization: Bearer ${this.auth.getToken()}
              }
            });
            return next.handle(request);
          }
        }
```

In the code above, if  I remove the URL on request clone, I'm able to see my custom header as part of the request header. If I put a URL in the `request.clone` method, my custom header no longer adds to the request header. It adds a value of **Access-control-Request-Header: authorization**. Could someone help me on this?

**Edit**
Does we need do anything at server side to expose this custom header.If it is on same origin header is appending if it different origin it is not appending

Comment: [httpInterceptor](https://v5.angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest) - This link may help you.

Comment: Where are you trying to see the headers ? I know for sure that its possible, I've already done it.

Comment: can you try updated solution.

Comment: the updated solution  is my actual implementation.I found the issue check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue and  the problem is at server side. When you hit a service which is running at different origin we need to set the custom header name at server side safe 
cors header list. After updating the list at server side now I am able to see the header in request.